# Get child/children component(s) using viewContainerRef in Angular2

Tags: angular

Within component we can get child components using following constructs:

```
@ViewChildren(MdVerTabLabelWrapper) _labelWrappers: QueryList<MdVerTabLabelWrapper>;
@ViewChildren(MdVerInkBar) _inkBar: QueryList<MdVerInkBar>;
```

However if I have viewContainerRef reference then how do I get child component(s)?

Basically what I am trying to do is I have list of components and I need to find children of those components programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

The ViewContainerRef class has length and get(index) properties for accessing children.  See the API here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html

So to reference a specific child, you use `viewContainerRef.get(childOfInterestIndex)`, and to work on all children you use a for loop, using something like `for(var index = 0; index < viewContenrRef.length; index++)`

Comment: The elements are actually siblings not children of the element referenced by `ViewContainerRef`.