# Recover dynamically generated component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that receives some data an generates some other components dynamically (ngx-charts).

> This is the directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ad-host]',
})
export class PresentationDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
}
```

> The template is pretty simple

```
<div class="presentation">
  <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
</div>
```

> Here starts the main component

```
presentations: Presentation[] = new Array();
components: any[] = new Array();
```

On init I go through an array of data and call the function loadComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
  const temp = this.simulationResponse['presentations'];
  for (const presentation of temp) {
    this.presentations.push(presentation);
    this.loadComponent(this.getComponent(presentation['type']), 
    presentation['data']);
  }
}
```

This functions returns the component, I added this one just to clarify the question.

```
getComponent(componentType: string) {
  switch (componentType) {
    case 'PIE': {
      return PieChartComponent;
    }
    case 'BAR': {
      return BarChartComponent;
    }
  }
}
```

Load Component creates a component each time that is called and sets the data that the component needs to build the graphic

```
loadComponent(component: any, data: any) {
  const componentFactory = 
  this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
  const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
  const componentRef = 
  viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  this.components.push(componentRef);
  (<AddData>componentRef.instance).single = data;
}
```

When data changes I call other function called updatePresentations

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.updatePresentations();
}
```

But here, in the last line inside the for when I try to assign the data I get two errors

```
updatePresentations() {
  const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
  for (let i = 0; i < viewContainerRef.length; i++) {
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.get(i);
    const tmp = this.presentations[i];
    (<AddData>componentRef.instance).single = tmp['data'];
  }
}
```

First Error

> ERROR in src/app/simulator/presentation/presentation.component.ts(71,7): >error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Second Error

> Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.
>   src/app/simulator/presentation/presentation.component.ts(71,30): error >TS2339: Property 'instance' does not exist on type 'ViewRef'.

I'm not worring me about the first one yet, the one that is killing me is the second, it says that instance is not a property of ViewRef, but I'm getting that object from the place that I stored it and it worked fine in the last line of LoadComponent function.

I'm so burnt that I can't see what I'm missing, any help will be more than welcome.

### Extra data:

I based mostly on this part of the angular guide to build this
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Whichever line that error is on, you're trying to assign an object to something that has been typed as an array. Can you please let us know which is line 71?

Comment: Where did you find that `vcRef.get` should return `ComponentRef`?

Comment: Sure, line 71 would be the last one of UpdatePresentation
(<AddData>componentRef.instance).single = tmp['data'];

Comment: @yurzui, from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983984/get-child-children-components-using-viewcontainerref-in-angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but as @yurzui implied, it appears that `viewContainerRef.get(i)` returns a `ViewRef` and not the `ComponentRef` that you want; see the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#get).  Why not use `this.components[i]` instead?